# How to create CMakeLists.txt on DJI OnboardSDK 3.2

Tags: cmake, dji-sdk

I'm trying to add the OnboardSDK **3.2** as a library for my project. I know there is a guide on how to integrate it on the docs, but it's only valid for version 3.3

My project has this structure:

```
oes-test\
├── build\
├── inc\
|   └── main.h
├── lib\
|   └── Onboard-SDK\
├── src\
|   └── main.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

This is a part of my `main.cpp` file:

```
// System Headers
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>

// DJI Linux Application Headers
#include "LinuxSerialDevice.h"
#include "LinuxThread.h"
#include "LinuxSetup.h"
#include "LinuxCleanup.h"
#include "ReadUserConfig.h"

...
```

And this is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(oes-test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread -g -O0")

if(NOT ONBOARDSDK_SOURCE)
    set(ONBOARDSDK_SOURCE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Onboard-SDK")
endif()

include_directories(${ONBOARDSDK_SOURCE}/osdk-core/inc)
include_directories(${ONBOARDSDK_SOURCE}/osdk-wrapper/inc)
include_directories(${ONBOARDSDK_SOURCE}/platform/linux/inc)
include_directories(inc)

FILE(GLOB SOURCE_FILES inc/*.h src/*.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} djiosdk-core djiosdk-platform djiosdk-wrapper)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION bin)
```

When I run `cmake ..` from the `build` directory, everything runs ok, but the problem comes when I run `make`. I get an error stating that `LinuxSerialDevice.h` cannot be found.
I'm sure I'm missing something in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, but I don't know what.

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

I had to add:

```
add_subdirectory(${ONBOARDSDK_SOURCE}/osdk-core)
add_subdirectory(${ONBOARDSDK_SOURCE}/osdk-wrapper)
add_subdirectory(${ONBOARDSDK_SOURCE}/platform/linux)
```

Under the `include_directories` block to make it work.
Hope it helps someone!